# Bumps on bottom of text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, cc-2018

For some reason in one of my Illustrator documents, there are small bumps on the bottom of the lowercase E and C characters.

[image: Example]

The font I'm using is (I believe) built into Windows. It's called Bahnschrift.

Any help with this would be appreciated. If a sample document is needed please let me know in the comments.

Also, Adobe Illustrator CC 2018.

Comment: If it's merely that particular font, it may be a bad font.

Comment: @Scott When using Photoshop, the font does not have this problem even at extremely high resolutions.

Comment: I don' t know then. I've never seen Illustrator mangle glyphs in a font like that. I suppose it *could* happen but I'd have no clue how to fix it. If you create outlines in AI do they go away?

Comment: Try the solution of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/852357), let see if it helps.

Comment: @Danielillo The "Type > Character" menu seems unavailable for me. Could it be somewhere else?

Comment: It's not a menu, it's the Character Palette.

Comment: @DanielilloI'm sorry I'm very new to Adobe products. Could you describe in more detail where this panel is or under what conditions it exists?

This is the closest thing I could find, it has no options for "sharp" or "crisp". https://image.ibb.co/mKjcaq/image.png

Comment: You have the right panel. Just below the close X there's a square which opens the panel menu. Select there "Show Options". The panel grows substantially.

Comment: @user287001 The option appears to be disabled for me. I tried turning off GPU preview, no dice.

Comment: I think  we are fighting against the wrong enemy. Options none, sharp, crisp, strong are antialiasing  settings. They have meaning only in pixel previews and bitmap exports.

Comment: (continued) The suggested PSD import case is different than your font rendering problem. I must admit I haven't any idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: @user287001 That was my thinking as well but I was willing to try anything. Antialiasing should only fix the edges of adjacent colors.

Comment: I should add that when I import the file into Inkscape, the issue goes away. But I prefer Illustrator (I use Inkscape for the command line) and don't want to have to use two programs.

Comment: I can confirm the problem exists in Illustrator CC, on Windows 10, and that changing the anti-aliasing setting doesn't fix it. Changing the variable font width setting to 79 or less seems to fix it. Inkscape displays the font properly, although it doesn't support the variable settings. I suppose the next step is to report it as a bug to Adobe.

Comment: @BillyKerr The bug can also be in the font. BTW old Multiple Master fonts (= a kind of Type 1 extension) are now back in another format.  They vanished when Adobe stopped to support ATM (=Type Manager). In Win7 it still could be used with trickery. I haven't tried the same in Win10.

Comment: @user287001 - since the font displays properly in other software including Photoshop, and Inkscape, the fault would seem to be with Illustrator.

Comment: I wonder if switching from GPU preview to CPU preview would help. Also if exported files don't have this bump, then it's not much of a problem.

Comment: @Joonas I have tried that, CPU preview didn't fix it. Also tried changing the graphics processor for Illustrator on my laptop. Same problem in multiple computers, it appears to be a bug in Illustrator. It is a problem because the exported SVG (and presumably other vector format) files have this defect as well. Raster is for some reason less noticeable, but it is still there especially on high resolution exports that have been downsampled to fit on your screen.

Comment: It sounds like raster anti-aliasing hides it a little. I guess there's not a whole lot you can do... I've only ever seen something similar in Indesign, when I've imported files where the text was hugging the edge of the original document...

Answer (score 1):

This is pure guessing. I haven't the needed software to try the thing I suspect.

Illustrator CC supports variable fonts to some degree, some of them are even included. The following links tell about it and show how to adjust.

https://theblog.adobe.com/can-variable-fonts-illustrator-cc/

https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/what-are-variable-fonts--cms-31310

Microsoft's  Bahnschrift is also variable. It can have some parameter out of Illustrator's pleasant rendering range. Check, if Illustrator allows you to adjust it.